# Term Extraction and Sentiment Analysis Open Source Project

Tags: open-source, nlp, machine-learning

I want to extract important terms from a text and create a domain specific term set. Then I want to learn how these words are used in text, positively or negatively.

Do you know any open source project which will help me to accomplish this tasks?

Edit:

Example Text:

```
"Although car is not comfortable, I like the design of it."
```

From this text, I want to extract something like these:

```
design:        positive
comfort(able): negative
```

Answer (score 2):

For parsing the text and getting the parts of speech you want, there are lots of toolkits

http://incubator.apache.org/opennlp/

http://www.nltk.org/

etc.

Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentiment_analysis for ideas about finding how words are used positively or negatively, if what you mean by that is connotation.  I don't know of any solid platforms for doing this, but maybe you can tell us more about your problem for some ideas.

In absence of a toolkit that'll do this for you, you might find that getting NPs and the ADJs linked to them would be sufficient.  You'd also need negation detection. I've used this ohnlp.sourceforge.net (build on Apache UIMA) and it comes with a negation detection algorithm that is moderately decent.

Comment: I second NLTK. Theres a good line of blog postings explaining how to use it for exactly this purpose starting here:http://streamhacker.com/2010/05/10/text-classification-sentiment-analysis-naive-bayes-classifier/